# BCM43142A0 Broadcom Bluetooth doesn't work with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, broadcom

I can see that many people have problems with this, but many slightly different answers are adding to my confusion. hoping that someone can guide me through this specifically.

I have a hp notebook 15 with Windows 10 (Bluetooth works there). I repartitioned the drive and installed Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel 4.15.0-33.generic). I managed to configure most everything but blueman tells me there are no adaptors.

When I started, I was getting complaints about missing firmware. I managed to download something (at this point I can't remember exactly what) but now
`lsusb` gives me

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
```

`grep`-ing through `dmesg` gives me

```
[   27.974968] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22  
[   27.974987] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized  
[   27.974990] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized  
[   27.974993] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized  
[   27.974999] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized  
[   28.094367] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70  
[   28.095366] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06  
[   28.111368] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A  
[   28.111371] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000  
[   30.816147] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0a0a tx timeout  
[   35.256748] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3  
[   35.256750] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast  
[   35.256754] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized  
[   38.880071] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch command 0a0a failed (-110)  
[   41.056139] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout 
[   49.120058] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)  
[ 1637.728121] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout  
[ 1645.792154] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
```

At some point I copied
`BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0277.0289.hex` and `BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0311.0328.hex` over from the Windows partition, but again, I don't know what to do with them.

I'm not exactly a noob, but the road signs all seem to be written in a language I can't quite translate. Any suggestions/comments would be gratefully appreciated. If I need to post more info, pls tell what else would be useful.

finally i went back to windows, looked in the device manager for the `.hex` file that windows uses. copied it again to the linux side. ran it through `hex2hcd`, then moved the output to `\lib\firmware\brcm` as both `BCM.hcd` and `BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd` based on the info returned by `lsusb` (`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device`). rebooted one more time, and voila!. it is now working. it seems like i did all this before but apparently not.

how do i mark this question as solved? editing the title tells me that's a no-no.

Comment: you can copy it to **your answer**

Comment: On my system there are 71 of those BCM*.hex. How do you know which one to use? E.g. BCM20702A1_001.002.014.1443.1488.hex to BCM20702A1_001.002.014.1483.1709.hex. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: i think i looked in windows->device manager->bluetooth->that adaptor's properties. somewhere in there it should say which file windows uses. then i copied that file over to linux.

Comment: What about any solution when I don't have any Windows machine available, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i went back to windows, looked in the device manager for the `.hex` file that windows uses. copied it again to the linux side. ran it through `hex2hcd`, then moved the output to `\lib\firmware\brcm` as both `BCM.hcd` and `BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd` based on the info returned by `lsusb` (`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device`). rebooted one more time, and voila!. it is now working. it seems like i did all this before but apparently not.

how do i mark this question as solved? editing the title tells me that's a no-no.

`@abu_bua` (tx) suggested moving my solution to be an answer, rather than editing the original post, so here it is.

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me on 20.10 I had to

- get the file from a windows driver look for my PID 216c with grep,
- open the inf and find the hex file using hex2hid
- then all worked as above

Hope it helps someone